# How To implement double exposure for picking images?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uiimage

In my app I'm  having two imageviews, first imageview will be constant and for second imageview ,after picking image it will zoom and it can be place any where in the view and second image  will be merged with first image and after merging second imageview will be nil and first imageview will be having two images and we can pic as many images in second imageview and can move anywhere but we need pic only single image at single time.How to implement this.?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is new question.Please reply me

Answer (score 0):

A simple image usually has 32bit of color information per pixel (rgb: ff ff ff), a grayscale image has 8bit.
It should be obvious that a conversion from 32bit to 8bit is not reversible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Then how to get original image..?

Comment: not reversible meaning impossible - your only option would be to go through all pictures in the lib, convert them to grayscale and compare (actually a few pixel should be enough) - or even better keep track of the original image in the first place

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you have to keep a copy of your original Image.

When you select Image from gallery save it in one UIImage object as original image before applying any grayscale on that.

Make another copy of selected Image and apply grayscale on that and assign this image to ImageView.

Now when you touch on this ImageView (Detect touch using Gestures) set originalImage to the ImageView.

**Edit:**
You can have function like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
                      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  [picker release];

          // Edited image works great (if you allowed editing)
  UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
          // AND the original image works great
  UIImage *originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
          // AND do whatever you want with it, (NSDictionary *)info is fine now 
}
```

In above code you can declare both `editedImage` and `originalImage` variables at global scope, assign `editedImage` as image for your `ImageView` and on touch on `ImageView` you can show `originalImage`

Comment: while picking the image it should save as a grayscale but how to get copy of original image?

Comment: Are you editing image with UIImagePicker and saving edited image in UIImagePicker delegate?

Comment: I'm using didFinishPickingmediawithInfo method to pick and saving it in uiimageview while saving only it is changing to grayscale

Comment: Please reply me If you are Knowing